# Hello everyone, please help me check this IF statement in Google app script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to make a code to assign logic input for my sheet. I use IF to make it. My code ran successfully but the logic didn't work. I have checked it many times, but I couldn't find something wrong. Can you help me with this? I'm stuck. Please review my example sheet and my script for more information. Thank you! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eV2SZ45Gs6jISgh_p6RIx-rfOGlHUM6vF114Mgf6c58/edit#gid=0

```
function logic(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "mama" && activeCell.getValue() == "Yes") {
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,1).setValue("1");
  } if (activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "mama" && activeCell.getValue() == "Hafl") {
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,1).setValue("1/2");
  } if (activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "mama" && activeCell.getValue() == "No") {
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,1).setValue(0);
  }

}
```

Comment: `but the logic didn't work` What's the desired logic? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code this way.
(Note that I use the const variable declaration instead of var ([ES6 - V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#modern_ecmascript_syntax)))

```
function logic() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    const activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();

    if (activeCell.getColumn() === 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "mama") {
        switch(activeCellValue) {
            case 'Yes':
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).setValue('1');
                break;
            case 'Half':
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).setValue('1/2');
                break;
            case 'No':
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
                activeCell.offset(0, 1).setValue('0');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you only have to test the common conditions once.
Using the [Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) function clearly shows the behavior of the script depending on the input value 'ActiveCellValue'.

Comment: Thank you Halijean, your code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you need that only one action resolve per run, you need to use else if to chain the statements:

```
if(statement){
    Action
}else if (statement2){
    Action2
}else if...
```